# Loader not being shown after setting state inside a function used for api call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I'm currently fetching monthly/quarterly/yearly data in my SalesOverview1 comp based on which tab the user clicks on. After fetching the data, I'm populating the charts which get updated based on the monthly/quarterly/yearly metric. Here are the 3 tabs:

[image]

The problem is that after clicking the monthly/quarterly/yearly tab, there is a delay during which the data is being fetched but I'm not able to see a loader even though I have added it in the code.

I'm using a state called loading which by default is set to false, but when a user clicks on the monthly/quarterly/yearly tab, it gets set to true inside the function that I've used. After the api call is done, I set it to false again inside the function. Here is the SalesOverview1 comp:

```
   lass SalesOverview1 extends Component {

state = {
    page_id: 4,
    hcp_id: 101,
    sales_overview_data: [],
    show_data: false,
    time_period: 'month',
    loading: false
}

  toggleTimePeriod = (timePeriod) => {
    this.setState({ ...this.state, loading: true, sales_overview_data: [] });
    let monthly = false;
    let quarterly = false;
    let yearly = false;
    if (timePeriod === 'month') {
        monthly = true;
    }
    else if (timePeriod === 'quarter') {
        quarterly = true;
    }
    else if (timePeriod === 'year') {
        yearly = true;
    }
    console.log('Clicked on sales Overview time period tab');
    console.log('state: ', this.state);
    axios.post('/test-json', {
        page_id: this.state.page_id,
        hcp_id: this.state.hcp_id,
        time_period: timePeriod
    })
        .then((res) => {
            this.setState({ ...this.state, loading: true });
            this.setState({ ...this.state, sales_overview_data: res.data });
            console.log('State after loading data in sales overview time period tab: ', this.state);
            this.setState({ ...this.state, loading: false });
        }, (error) => {
            console.log(error);
        });
    this.setState({ ...this.state, monthly: monthly, quarterly: quarterly, yearly: yearly });
    console.log('state inside toggletimeperiod: ', this.state);
}
```

As you can see above, I'm setting the loading state to true inside toggleTimePeriod function and then to false after the api data is fetched.

Below is the return code:

```
  <>
            <div role="tabpanel" id="tablet-3" class="tab-pane" >
                <div class="panel-body" style={{ backgroundColor: "rgb(243,243,244)", border: "none", margin: 0 }}>
                    {
                        this.state.sales_overview_data.length === 0 || this.state.loading === true ?
                            <>
                                <Loader
                                    style={{ marginLeft: '450px', marginTop: '10px' }}
                                    type="Circles"
                                    color="#0caf8d"
                                    height={50}
                                    width={50}
                                    radius={30}
                                />
                            </>
                            :
                            <>
                                <div class="row " style={{ marginBottom: 15 }} >
                                    <div class=" col-12 float-right">
                                        <div class="btn-group">
                                            <button onClick={() => { this.toggleTimePeriod('month') }}
                                                Monthly
                                            </button>
                                            <button onClick={() => { this.toggleTimePeriod('quarter') }}
                                                Quarterly
                                            </button>
                                            <button onClick={() => { this.toggleTimePeriod('year') }}
                                                Yearly
                                            </button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class='row'>
                                    {
                                        this.state.sales_overview_data.length !== 0 &&
                                        <ChartBox
                                            data={this.state.sales_overview_data[401]}
                                        />
                                    }
                               .....................
```

I haven't added the closing divs in the above code, you guys can assume that there's no issue with that. In the html, I'm first checking the length of the state sales_overview_data and the boolean value of the state loading, and based on that I'm deciding on the loader.
If I am initially on the Dashboard tab and then I click on the Sales Overview tab, I see the loader and it works fine. But when I'm already on the Sales Overview tab and then when I click on say quarterly, I don't see the loader. However, after fetching the data, the charts get updated automatically.

I think there's an issue on where I'm setting state inside my function. You don't need to go through all the code, just on where I'm setting the loading state.

Have added a screenshot of the states. Please look at the lines that say: 'state inside sales overview comp:'. I'm console logging it inside my render just before return starts.

[image]

Comment: Pls attach a reproducible code link to the sandbox

Comment: How can I add code for the fetched data? Also, can you mention where you have doubts about the code. I can clear straight away. I've tried to be as elaborate as possible in my question as I haven't used sandbox before.

Comment: Does the loader component work properly in other places? Also, is api response setting the `sales_overview_data` correctly once the data is returned?

Comment: Try to mock the data fetch with Promise, e.g. `const fetchData = (mockResponse) => new Promise(res => setTimeout(() => res(mockResponse), 1000))`

Comment: Yes, loader works fine when I'm on another tab say Dashboard and then I switch to Sales Overview tab. Then the loader works until I fetch the data and then the charts get displayed. But the loader doesn't work when I'm already inside my Sales Overview tab and when I switch to monthly/quarterly/yearly tab. Now your 2nd question: yes, the api response is setting the sales_overview data.

Comment: The `.then()` handler of your axios call is only invoked when the request already finished. Also you set it to `loading: true` and then you set it to `loading: false` again in the same handler which is a noop.

Comment: @trixn I get what you are saying but then where should I set loading state to false?

Comment: Setting it to `false` in the `.then()` is correct. I'd suggest using [react-query](https://react-query.tanstack.com/) for data fetching. It will save you a lot of headaches when fetching data from an API and implements loading and error states as well as caching properly.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting react-query but is there a way to solve my problem without using react-query?

Comment: @ShridharK Sure, but from the code you have shown it should work. We don't know how `Loader` is implemented. Side note: You do not need to spread `this.state` into the state. `this.setState()` already does partial updates to the state. Also you are possibly overriding state updates by doing this. If anything you should use the callback version of `setState` to take the current state.

Comment: I have basically imported loader as a package react-loader-spinner. The package does all the work. Here is how I imported it: import Loader from "react-loader-spinner"; I know it should work but don't know why it isn't working. Is my condition inside return wrong?

Comment: The loader takes a `visible` prop which defaults to `false`. You need to set it to `true` in order to show the spinner. You can render it unconditionally and only set the `visible` prop according to the loading state.

Comment: But the loader works fine when I switch from the other tabs to sales overview. So I don't think that should be the case. But regardless, can you code it out by modifying my code? I can immediately test it.

Comment: Well I guess the docs are wrong about the default as it seems to be visible if the prop is not provided.

Comment: "You don't need to go through all the code, just on where I'm setting the loading state" How did you verify this? You shouldn't assume where the problem is but create a sandbox with a minimal example that reproduces the problem. This is what you should do **before** you ask a question here. There is a lot of unrelated code that is distracting from the actual problem.

Comment: @ShridharK create a new method in your class called `renderConditional()` and move the loader and the other conditional render into that method. Use good old if else instead of ternary operators and then call the `renderConditional()` method in your main render method, within curly braces. This will make it easier for you to manage your component and try to fix the issue.

Comment: Also note that console logging `this.state` right after calling `this.setState` will not show you the updated state but still the current state. State updates are async and will only be visible during the next render. This is also why you should never use `this.state` to update the state but use the callback version of `this.setState` as you may be accidentally overriding previous state updates with stale values.

Comment: @Tom Bombadil You mean the ternary operators are causing the issue? Ok, I can try that.

Comment: @ShridharK possible the ternary operator is the issue. Its really difficult to say given the code snippet. You should really break your code into smaller chunks as suggested above using methods that return renders or create a different component altogether. It should be easier for you to work with your files and even maintain them. Also, I can see a lot of unnecessary code like fragments, spreading state before each setState. But, don't worry keep at it. You will learn the tricks of writing clean code as you write more and more.

Comment: Have added a new screenshot. @Tom Bombadil Yes, I'll try to refactor the code as you said, will see if it works. I'm a complete newbie to React and they are asking me to build a complete software tool lol. Feel like quitting :|

Comment: @ShridharK welcome to frontend dev. I feel your pain mate. But, learn React. The demand for React Devs is way higher than the supply in the market. And the pay is pretty decent as well. A year or two of React experience and you'll have companies waiting for you. https://www.udemy.com/course/react-the-complete-guide-incl-redux/ Incase you are interested.

Comment: Link for a chat room: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230602/loader-rendering-inside-reactjs

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I've already done the course but I'll admit I rushed through it a bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://github.com/mhnpd/react-loader-spinner#proptypes-available) of the library you are using the is a `visible` prop that probably should be set to `true` in order to show the spinner:

```
<Loader
    visible={this.state.loading}
    style={{ marginLeft: '450px', marginTop: '10px' }}
    type="Circles"
    color="#0caf8d"
    height={50}
    width={50}
    radius={30}
/>
```

EDIT:

The problem might be that you set the loading state to `false` again right after the `axios.post()` by spreading the old `this.state` into the state update. Can you replace the code of `toggleTimePeriod` with that and try if it works?:

```
toggleTimePeriod = (timePeriod) => {
    this.setState({
        loading: true, 
        sales_overview_data: [],
        monthly: timePeriod === 'month',
        quaterly: timePeriod === 'quarter',
        yearly: timePeriod === 'year',
    });

    axios.post('/test-json', {
        page_id: this.state.page_id,
        hcp_id: this.state.hcp_id,
        time_period: timePeriod
    }).then(res => {
        this.setState({
            loading: false, 
            sales_overview_data: res.data,
        });
    }, error => console.log(error)); 
}
```

Comment: Apologies for the delay in replay, I was in a meeting. I tried as you suggested over here but it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: @ShridharK It's next to impossible to debug this with only the snippet you provided. Maybe the tab contents aren't rendering as you think when switching tabs. did you confirm in the react dev tools that the `Loader` component is in the tree after switching tabs?

Comment: I'm very very new to React so I don't understand what you mean by the Loader component being in the tree. I did console.log in my render method and what I observed was this: The component is getting rendered 4 times when I switch the time period tab. Only in the 3rd render, I can see the loading state to be true. In the 1st, 2nd and 4th renders, the loading state is false. Should I pass a snippet of it?

Comment: Scratch that, the loading state is true only in the 2nd and 3rd render and is false in the 1st and 4th renders.

Comment: Have you installed the [react dev tools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi)? With that you can inspect the component tree in the chrome devtools. It's pretty essential whenever trying to debug components. So if the loading state is `true` the and the spinner component is rendered, it should show.

Comment: @trixn you deserve an upvote simply for your efforts mate. You've been helping Shridhar for quite some time now. Kudos.

Comment: Have added a new screenshot in my question. I think I have installed it but I don't know how to use it. I'm the only who know a little of ReactJS on the project that I'm working on and I don't even have any senior Dev to take help from.

Comment: @ShridharK Is the full code publicly available anywhere? The issue might not be in the code shown so far.

Comment: I can share the full code of the component I'm referring to (SalesOverview1). Do you know of a good website other than Code Sandbox where I can just paste it? Of course, this is company code as well so I'm not completely sure about it.

Comment: @ShridharK You can share the full code of the specific component in your question. I guess that this is a bootstrap v4 tab panel? I'm specifically interested in seeing, how the content of each panel is rendered.

Comment: @ShridharK So you added the `Loader` component to the panel with the id `tablet-3`. Did you also add it to the other panels? Is it possible that the loader is only shown in that specific panel but not in the other panels?

Comment: So should I edit my question to display the full code of SalesOverview1? The code will contain everything that comes under the Sales Overview Tab. There are a few child components like ChartBox(for displaying charts) and TableBox(for displaying tables) and there are absolutely no issues in them, you can trust me on that. But I'll tell you in advance: you've already seen the main relevant code as I don't think you'll find anything relevant pertaining to the issue I'm facing in the extra code that I share.

Comment: Yes, I've added the Loader to other tab panels and I'm facing the same issue in others as well. When I switch to other tab panels, the loader is seen, the charts get rendered after data is pulled (for the default monthly time period tab). But again when I switch the time period tab from monthly to quarterly, I don't see the loader when the data is getting fetched. But just like in the Sales Overview tab, the charts get updated automatically to show quarterly data (without showing loader in the interval). The code in other tabs is similar to the Sales Overview tab so I face the same problem.

Comment: @ShridharK I've updated my answer with how the correct `toggleTimePeriod` should look like. It might be that you are overriding the loading state with your last `this.setState` call. As I already mentioned you should **never** update the state using `this.state` as it might be stale because it does not contain the data of previous state updates in the same handler. Or in other words, if `this.state.loading` was `false` at the beginning of the handler you set it to `false` again immediately with your last `setState` which will override any updates before it as it gets batched by react.

Comment: @ShridharK Also note that if the console logs are the ones from the `toggleTimePeriod` you will not get the correct results. `this.state` will not show the updated state after calling `this.setState`. It  will only show the current state which will only be updated during the next render.

Comment: It's still working the same way as previously. "As I already mentioned you should never update the state using this.state as it might be stale because it does not contain the data of previous state updates in the same handler." - I have always used this.setState to set the state. I don't see any location in my code where I'm using this.state to set the state.

Comment: Yes, I understand that the console logs to check the state inside the function won't be the correct ones and the correct ones will only be after the next render. I just added the console logs for general checking.

Comment: @ShridharK You are spreading `this.state` into the next state that you pass to `this.setState()`. This is what I mean. This is a mistake. **NEVER** do that. Use the callback version of `this.setState` if you need to access the current state in order to update the state. Also you don't need to spread it in the first place as this is what `this.setState` will  do anyways. It will merge the current state with the values provided without it.

Comment: Ok, got what you wanted to say and you have solved my problem! Thanks a ton! Wish I could give you some reward for just being so patient. Thanks again sir!

Comment: @ShridharK You are welcome. Good luck for the future. Also read [Why is setState giving me the wrong value?](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html#why-is-setstate-giving-me-the-wrong-value) for an explanation from the docs for why you shouldn't rely on `this.state` to update the state. It specifially is a problem if you have multiple `this.setState` calls in the same handler which is the case here.

Comment: Yes, I'll look into the link:) My email id is: shridhar.kanitkar23@gmail.com if you want to stay in touch :) Good luck for the future to you as well.

Comment: @ShridharK Last note: If you are just learning react I strongly suggest you do it by learning react with hooks. Class components are not the recommended way to write components anymore. Unfortunately the docs aren't very up-to-date to cover this with examples as they are currently in the process of updating them. Also have a look at react-query which makes data fetching much less painful as there are many things to consider (re-fetching, failed requests, caching, pagination). This lib will do the complicated stuff for you and leave for you what matters for your business logic.

Comment: Will look into what you have suggested. Thanks for the suggestions!